# How to click on button using Xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, button, xpath, webdriver

```
<td class="tdDiv">
<div class="divElem">
<ul class="ulElem">
<li role="presentation" class="ng-star-inserted">
<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="">
<span class="name">Admin Service</span></button></li>
<li role="presentation" class="ng-star-inserted">
<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="">
<span class="name">Database</span></button></li>
<li role="presentation" class="ng-star-inserted">
<button type="button" tabindex="0">
<span class="name">E-mail</span></button></li>
```

I want to select <kbd>Email</kbd> button, but not able to select using `xPath`,

Tried many ways, please provide me exact XPath. I used below `xPath`

```
//*[@type='button']/span[contains(text(), 'E-mail')]
```

Comment: Please show what have you tried. It is better if you can provide a minimum reproducible code. Thank you!

Comment: According to HTML-sample text is `E-mail` not `Email`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your xPath is valid. What are you trying to do? Select or click? and What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can't select button with this locator: `//*[@type='button']/span[contains(text(), 'E-mail')]`.

Because none of the buttons contains a text of `E-mail`. That text is inside `<span>` element. Instead, you can, first, locate `<span>` element with `E-mail` text, then select `button` inside it:

```
 `//*span[contains(text(), 'E-mail')]/button`
```